# Нужна ли запятая «В связи с последними событиями(,) у меня появилось много свободного времени»

Tags: пунктуация

> В связи с последними событиями(,) у меня появилось много свободного времени.

Comment: А Вы как предполагаете? Нужна или нет? Мы тут просто сами пытаемся в этом разобраться, и возможно Ваша версия наведет нас на какие-либо мысли.

Answer (score 1):

Грамота: «В СВЯЗИ С (чем), предлог. Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «в связи с», могут обособляться. О факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Прил. 1» (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_113 ).
В Вашем случае запятая не нужна, хотя поставить её — не ошибка: она факультативна.

Answer (score 1):

***В связи с последними собЫтиями  // у меня появилось много свободного врЕмени.***

1. Факультативность постановки запятой – это **общее решение** для обстоятельственных оборотов, включающих производные предлоги, нам же нужно предложить **конкретное** решение. Если возможны оба варианта, то следует выбрать более подходящий или обозначить смысловые оттенки вариантов, чтобы автор сам сделал выбор.
2. Я считаю, что в данном случае решение **однозначное**: запятая здесь не нужна.  Все дело в том, что это предложение недостаточно распространено, чтобы выделить оборот в отдельную обособленную структуру.  Это простое предложение из двух фраз, разделенных паузой по схеме «тема – рема», то есть предмет и сообщение о предмете.
3. Попробуем **распространить** предложение:  ***В связи с последними событиями, у меня наконЕц-то появилось // много свободного врЕмени.***

Здесь обособление оборота  (для придания ему большей **значимости**)  возможно,  так как  вторую часть предложения  можно разделить паузой на две фразы. Но если выделение оборота не является необходимым  по смыслу в данном тексте, то его можно не обособлять. Теперь уже автор делает свой выбор,  то есть решение становится факультативным.

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ  (комментарий)

Красиво говорите, Jim Korbett, просто заслушаешься. Рассуждаете вы о том, как должно быть. А если все происходит **не по вашему сценарию**, то как вы поступите? Возможны **два варианта.**  (1) Можно отрицать действительность за то, что она «неправильная». (2) Можно скорректировать свои взгляды. Давайте посмотрим, что вы выберете.

Я достаю свои старые конспекты с этой темой, где приведены **парные варианты**, вполне себе приличные (взятые из художественных произведений или из реальной речи; в любом случае, не мои личные, а из учебников). Вы их просматриваете и делаете свой вывод.

(1) Дорога в горах, **ввиду** обвалов, была непроходимой. Полёт отложен **ввиду** особых обстоятельств.

(2) **Вследствие** одной неприятной сцены, я рассорился с ним окончательно. **Вследствие** дождей посевные работы затянулись.

(3) **В силу** сложившихся условий, мы решили отказаться от поездки. **В силу** этого моё положение ухудшилось.

(4) Катер, **в связи** с волнением на море, был вынужден вернуться. Работы прекращены **в связи** с аварией.

(5)  **По случаю** плохой погоды, пароход пришёл позднее обычного. Вылет задержался **по случаю** большой облачности.

(6) Степан Аркадьевич в школе учился хорошо, **благодаря** своим способностям. Команда вышла в финал **благодаря** усиленным тренировкам.

(7) Иван Петрович, **по причине** своей неопытности, вскоре запустил хозяйство. **По причине** моего отъезда все в доме поднялись рано.

(8)  **За неимением** места во флигеле, мне отвели  комнату в графских хоромах. Паровозы перешли  на дрова **за неимением** угля.

Это только примеры с обстоятельствами причины,  а есть и другие (уступка, условие, цель, сравнение).

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, какие вообще ко мне претензии. Я не говорил, что любой причинный оборот обособляется. Если предложение говорится для того, что бы сообщить о причине чего-то — ударение падает на причинный оборот, то он естественно не обособляется; во всех других случаях причинный оборот обособляется всегда.

Comment: Найдите хоть одно предложение во всей художественной литературе, которое бы не соответствовало бы этому правилу.

Comment: — У вас какие-то проблемы?   
— Посевные работы затянулись, вследствие дождей.   

— Почему задержки в посевных работах.   
— Посевные работы затянулись вследствие дождей.   

— Почему вы не собираетесь?   
— Мы решили отказаться от поездки, в силу  
  сложившихся условий.
 
— Почему вы отказались от поездки?   
— Мы решили отказаться от поездки в силу сложившихся условий.   

— Почему прекратились работы?   
— Работы прекращены в связи с аварией.   

— Почему нет рабочих в столовой?   
— Работы прекращены, в связи с аварией.

Comment: В связи с последними событиями, у меня появилось много свободного времени. Попробуйте придумать контекст, где в этом предложении не нужно было бы ставить запятую.

Comment: Если быть честным, то я разобрался в теме на 100 процентов, только когда взглянул на ваши примеры. Мы оба дали неправильный ответ. Мой ответ правильный(запятая ставится), но из неправильных представлений, ваш ответ неправильный(запятая не ставится), но из чуть менее неправильных представлений.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится, так как это причинный оборот.
По причине неудачного выступления, спортсмены были подавлены.
Благодаря таянию снегов, мы легко могли различать дорогу.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу с вами согласиться, но надеюсь, что вы поймете почему.1. Значение  причины  является поводом для обособления определений и приложений, так как оно для этих оборотов дополнительное, а при обособлении мы его подчеркиваем. Но для обстоятельственного оборота это основное и единственное значение, поэтому обособление таких оборотов факультативное. 2. Обособление во многом  зависит   от структуры конкретного  предложения, также очень важна его распространенность.

Comment: Поэтому мы не можем ориентироваться на другие предложения, которые вы приводите в качестве примеров, для каждого из них – свое решение.  3. Также  желательно обратить  внимание на следующий факт: не доверяйте «придуманным» примерам,  лучше берите их  из  художественной литературы.  Тогда они органично связаны с текстом, там обоснованность обособления  следует из всего содержания, а не только определяется  по одному заданному предложению.

Comment: Приведите тогда пример причинного оборота, который бы не обособлялся и объясните причину, по которой он не обособляется.

Comment: Благодаря дождям посевы зазеленели. Пример взят из ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121
В нераспространенном предложении  и в препозиции  оборот со значением причины не обособляется, его даже прочитать нельзя с обособлением. Но добавьте несколько слов, и у вас будет возможность  подчеркивать причину или не подчеркивать причину (факультативный вариант): Благодаря дождям, посевы пшеницы быстро зазеленели. Обособление даже от контекста зависит, нужно читать весь фрагмент, чтобы понять необходимость подчеркивания оборота.

Comment: На мой взгляд, термин «распространенное» можно применять только в значении «больше, чем одно слово в обороте» и «наличие собственных знаков препинания в обороте или части сложного предложения». Нельзя применять термин «распространенные» в значении «много или мало слов», так как тут нет точных критериев. Мало это сколько? Два? Семь? На мой взгляд, пунктуация — это набор базовых принципов и сохранение последовательности  по всей языковой комбинаторике. Если вы ставите запятую в предложении:«Политые дождем, посевы зеленели» — то и должны ставить в предложении: «Благодаря дождям, посевы зеленели.»

Comment: Мы уже часто говорили  о том, что любое утверждение не абсолютно, а верно в определенных пределах. Нераспространенность имеет определение в формальной грамматике, но в структурной грамматике уже свое понимание термина.  Базовые принципы тоже не надо считать абсолютом. В частности, структура определительных и обстоятельственных оборотов совершенно разная. Сравните:  Политые дождем посЕвы // зеленЕли. Удобно говорить без обособления?  Думаю, что нет. А вы ищете общие принципы для  разноструктурных конструкций. Поэтому ваше  "они должны" здесь не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Причинный оборот обособляется всегда, кроме тех случаев, когда говорящий произносит предложение для того, чтобы сообщить о причине чего-то (смысловое ударение падает на причинный оборот).

— Откуда у тебя так много свободного времени?
— У меня появилось много свободного времени в связи с последними событиями. Тетушка умерла, оставила мне наследство — и мне не нужно работать.

— Как поживаешь, Игорь?
—  У меня появилось много свободного времени, в связи с последними событиями.
— Я слышал про твою тетушку.

В предложении: «В связи с последними событиями, у меня появилось много свободного времени», где причинный оборот предшествует основной части, крайне трудно придумать контекст, где бы предложение произносилось для сообщения причины, по которой у человека появилось много свободного времени и, соответственно, не ставилась бы запятая.

Comment: Прочитала я ваши записи;  чуть позже, возможно,  выскажу свое мнение. Пока же приведу пример. Представьте себе, что собеседник в курсе  ваших "последних событий",  а вы ему говорите: "Да, я вам обязательно помогу. В связи с последними событиями  // у меня появилось много свободного времени". Интонация спокойная, нейтральная, обособление и выделение причинного значения не требуется.

Comment: Нет, в приведенном примере предложение произносится в первую очередь для того, что бы сообщить, что у говорящего появилось много свободного времени(помогу, потому что появилось много свободного времени). Ударение падает не на причинный оборот, поэтому он обособляется.

Comment: Ну что ж, нет так нет, тем проще для меня. Хотела вам объяснить разницу интонационных схем, а также семантики  при обособлении и без обособления, но теперь не буду, оставлю  информацию при себе.   Все-таки общение с вами добавило мне определенные знания, прояснило кое-какие тонкости,  так что спасибо за  беседу.  И желаю успехов в работе на форуме.